# Iterate an array of arrays for a match from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays, and I would like to iterate this array with the values of another array looking for a match.

```
let arr1 = [[1,3,5],[2,4,7],[1,5,9]] // [false, false, true]
let arr2 = [1,2,4,5,9] // arr2 contains all values of arr1[2]. return true.
```

I need it to return truthy falsey if all values in an arr1[i] are present in arr2

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  if (arr2.every(arr1[i])) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
let arr1 = [[1,3,5],[2,4,7],[1,5,9]];
let arr2 = [1,2,4,5,9];
let result = arr1.map(x => x.every(y => arr2.includes(y)));
console.log(result);
```

or [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you just want to get matching results:

```js
let arr1 = [[1,3,5],[2,4,7],[1,5,9]];
let arr2 = [1,2,4,5,9];
let result = arr1.filter(x => x.every(y => arr2.includes(y)));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Should technically use a `filter` over a `map` - `map` should always return the same amount of elements in the array it maps over.

Comment: @tymeJV included `.filter()` in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for a single boolean value by using [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for each inner array and check `array2` with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var array1 = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]],
    array2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9],
    result = array1.some(a => a.every(v => array2.includes(v)));
    
console.log(result);
```

Using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var array1 = [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 7], [1, 5, 9]],
    array2 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 9],
    result = array1.some((s => a => a.every(v => s.has(v)))(new Set(array2)));
    
console.log(result);
```